# How do I vertically correct the navigationBar's titleView text position when using a custom font?

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

We're using custom fonts for the titleView in the navigation bar.
Somehow Apple always draws this font too high.

How do I correct for this strange offset you get when you are using custom fonts in a navbar?

Comment: I'm using a custom font in iOS for the first time, and I'm seeing it drawn too high *everywhere*, not just in the title bar. If this is a general custom font problem, that's going to be pretty annoying to hack around.

Comment: @MusiGenesis actually, there's a new method like `[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:...` in iOS5 or later, which you can define the title style easily. And BTW, you can create a custom UILabel(even with category or subclassing), and then you can use it everywhere with the style you like. :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I used `setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:forBarMetrics:`.

<sup>**Compatibility:** available starting from iOS 5.</sup>

Comment: Wow I've seen so many convoluted fixes for this problem, and this one was all I needed. Thanks.

Comment: awesome, it pays to read on! What would life be like without SO?     [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:2.f forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

Answer (score 13):

Your can set a new view as `titleView`, then add a new label to it:

```
UIView * customTitleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 200.0f, 40.0f)];

UILabel * customLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 20.0f, 200.0f, 20.0f)];
[customLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[customLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[customLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f]];
[customLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
[customLabel setText:@"Your Text"];
[customTitleView addSubview:customLabel];
[customLabel release];

[self.navigationItem setTitleView:customTitleView];
[customTitleView release];
```

Comment: what about when there is a back button and messes up the alignment center.  The size to fit method seems to be funky in that case

Comment: @MonkeyBonkey so I prefer customize the navigation bar totally, including the back button. :)

Comment: @HariKaramSingh have you tried to fix the `frame.origin.y` of `customLabel` to meet your requirement?

Comment: I'm using initWithFrame with a negative value for y in CGRectMake.  I also tried shortening the height to match. No luck...

Comment: @HariKaramSingh not a good solution, but you can try to use a negative value for your `customTitleView`, and increase its height.