# How to make texts in UINavigation Bar Centered Vertically

Tags: objective-c, uitabbar, xcode4.5

I do this:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{UITextAttributeTextColor: navTextColor,UITextAttributeTextShadowColor: navTextColor,UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset: [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 0)],UITextAttributeFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:12],UITextAttributeFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:12]}];
```

The result is the text is smaller. However, it's posted too high.

[image]

I can fix that using

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:5 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

But sometimes I want to use UIText rather than just pics on the titleView and that get pushed down too.

It would be a very strange design I think to have text goes up like that. So what's the catch and how do I make title texts in UINavigationBar centered vertically as it is horizontally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9927708/1106035).

Other solution is set the `frame` of your `label view`. check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9916668/1106035)